# Facing issue while installing fancyimpute

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

For installing the fancyimpute, i am using the below commands:

```
conda install ecos

conda install CVXcanon

pip install fancyimpute
```

### On firing the 1st command "conda install ecos", i am getting the below error. Please help me on this resolution.

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(196): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Deepak\Anaconda3', env_name: 'None', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Deepak\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py']
/ DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Deepak\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Deepak\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::automat-0.7.0-py_1'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\Deepak\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\Deepak\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

---

Note: Tried the same command after using "conda clean --packages". But still the issue persists.

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: According to (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/ecos) you must run `conda install -c anaconda ecos` to install that package I guess

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6057) about the same problem (transaction also fails on **automat**), there are a few things that seem to get it working:

1. **Cleaning**. You've already tried `conda clean --packages`, so maybe you can ignore this one, but the thread also suggests `conda clean --all`. Personally, I think that's a bit blunt.  The users who it worked for may have only needed `--packages`.
2. **Update Conda**. Many seem to get around this by updating Conda, `conda update -n base conda`.
3. **Update Anaconda**. Some said it worked to run `conda update anaconda`.
4. **Freeze installed packages**. Some users noticed that it only happens when planned transactions include updating other packages. One can prevent other packages from updating by using `conda install --freeze-installed ecos`.
5. **Issue with latest Automat**. One user reports the issue is specific to the recent 0.7.0 version of Automat. They report having a successful transaction by explicitly requesting the previous Automat version, e.g., `conda install ecos automat=0.6.*`

### Recommendation

I would try **(2)** first.

Something I find strange in all this is that everyone reporting this is on Windows, but Conda attempts to install the **noarch** version (as indicated by the `py_1` in the tarball). Nothing particularly wrong with that, but on OSX, Conda specifically tries to install the **osx-64** version. Hence, I would attempt to explicitly install the **win-64** version of 0.7.0 and see if that works. That is,

```
conda install conda-forge/win-64::automat
```

If that doesn't work, I suppose I would try **(4)** or **(5)** next.